# Validation accuracy and Validation Loss starts decreasing rapidly and then starts increasing rapidly with CNN and Batch normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The validation accuracy starts increasing rapidly in a few epochs and then starts decreasing after adding Batchnormalization to the code.

My code is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
```

Kindly guide if this behaviour is and i should check for more epochs or i am doing something wrong here

The output is:

```
Epoch 13/200
433/433 - 2220s - loss: 0.3787 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8591 - auc: 0.9604 - val_loss: 0.3948 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.8529 - val_auc: 0.9584
Epoch 14/200
433/433 - 2206s - loss: 0.4009 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8495 - auc: 0.9559 - val_loss: 1.0093 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.6535 - val_auc: 0.8175
Epoch 15/200
433/433 - 2205s - loss: 0.3705 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8590 - auc: 0.9622 - val_loss: 1.9217 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4865 - val_auc: 0.6711
Epoch 16/200
433/433 - 2208s - loss: 0.3483 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8725 - auc: 0.9661 - val_loss: 1.7980 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5639 - val_auc: 0.7213
Epoch 17/200
433/433 - 2213s - loss: 0.3396 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8735 - auc: 0.9676 - val_loss: 10.1333 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1929 - val_auc: 0.4038
Epoch 18/200
433/433 - 2223s - loss: 0.3364 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8759 - auc: 0.9684 - val_loss: 0.5666 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.7819 - val_auc: 0.9228
Epoch 19/200
433/433 - 2249s - loss: 0.3292 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8782 - auc: 0.9695 - val_loss: 0.3376 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.8699 - val_auc: 0.9686
Epoch 20/200
433/433 - 2216s - loss: 0.3155 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8834 - auc: 0.9718 - val_loss: 1.3117 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.6213 - val_auc: 0.7883
```

Comment: It seemed to me after a point your model just starts to overfit.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the model starts overfitting. To prevent this, we have to add a dropout layer after `relu` activation layer.
Another approach to prevent overfitting is to add Early Stopping callback in `model.fit()`

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=400, verbose=0, callbacks=[es])
```

Comment: The problem is that the accuracy decreases to a very low value like 19% from 80% in a few epochs and then increases to a good value to 80-90% in one or two epochs and then starts decreasing and then increasing in a few epochs. It reaches from 19% to 80% in one epoch and this behaviour continues

Epoch 17/200
433/433 - 2213s - loss: 0.3396 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8735 - auc: 0.9676 - val_loss: 10.1333 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1929 

Epoch 18/200
433/433 - 2223s - loss: 0.3364 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8759 - auc: 0.9684 - val_loss: 0.5666 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.7819